What can be done to make the Twitter account more effective?
Currently, the hashtags added by the Twitter bot is just the most popular tag from the question. In many cases, the tag may be obscure, too broad (#python) or different from common usage (#pe -> physical education, private equity).
So, to make the Twitter bot more effective, what should be done?

Two solutions that come to my mind are :

If possible, an additional hashtag be used #reverseengineering
If not, only  #reverseengineering be used

